# Scapy/Kamene- How to extract packet and frame information?

Tags: python, scapy, packet, pcap

I am using scapy to read pcap files in order to extract some information. I can successfully pull attributes related to IP, TCP, UDP, etc., but I also need general packet and frame information such as:

```
       "packet_id",
        "num",
        "len",
        "caplen",
        "timestamp",
        "frame.offset_shift",
        "frame.time_epoch",
        "frame.time_delta",
        "frame.time_delta_displayed",
        "frame.time_relative",
        "frame.number",
        "frame.len",
        "frame.cap_len",
        "frame.marked",
        "frame.ignored".
```

Is there a way to extract these with scapy? I have managed to extract them with pyshark and I maybe thought to use both libraries at the same time, but this gives me other errors.

Comment: What kind of errors?

Comment: Well pyshark and scapy dont use the same method to read the pcap. I am currently using cap = rdpcap('pcap.pcap'). But also if I try to use pyshark to read the packet id, e.g. pkt.number, I get:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kamene/packet.py", line 1108, in getfield_and_val
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: number